# What are "big bad cheeseburgers"?

Tags: meaning

I came across a strange sentence while reading a story for kids.
"The true story of the Three Little Pigs".
The story is told by the wolf, his side of the story.
He says, "I don't know how this whole Big Bad Wolf thing got started, but it's all wrong. Maybe it's because of our diet. Hey, it's not my fault wolves eat cute little animals like bunnies and sheep and pigs. That's just the way we are. **If cheeseburgers were Big and Bad, too**."

This is how it is written. I cannot understand what he is talking about. Why cheeseburgers?

(Then several paragraphs later he mentions cheeseburgers again: "It seemed like a shame to leave a perfectly good ham ...in the straw. ... Think of as a big cheeseburger just lying there" - This cheeseburger-sentence is clear, but the first one is a mess for me)
Please help to understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You’re probably missing part of the sentence. It doesn’t make sense as you gave it. But an online transcript gives “If cheeseburgers **were cute, folks would probably think you** were Big and Bad, too,” which does make sense. I think this is a picture book; check whether you’re missing some words on the other side of an illustration or something like that.

Comment: Yes, you are right:  https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=1Q01X8JU3GU&autoplay=1